# Accounts XML from array, containing members

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I'm sure this has been asked before, but struggling to find the correct search terms.

I have an array; that is ultimately built from a SQL query

```
$users = array('peter','megan','michael');
```

What I am trying to end up is XML structure of each user, with the other user's in the array as members. Like:

```
<accounts>
    <user>
        <uid>peter</uid>
        <members>
            <user>megan</user>
            <user>michael</user>
        </members>
    </user>
    <user>
        <uid>megan</uid>
        <members>
            <user>peter</user>
            <user>michael</user>
        </members>
    </user>
    <user>
        <uid>michael</uid>
        <members>
            <user>peter</user>
            <user>megan</user>
        </members>
    </user>
</accounts>
```

Anyone shed some light on how to do this?

Comment: I think you want to search for `Php array unique combinations` and then `php array to xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$users = array('peter','megan','michael');

$accounts = new SimpleXmlElement('<accounts />');
foreach($users as &$uid) {
    $node = $accounts->addChild('user');
    $node->addChild('uid', $uid);
    $members = $node->addChild('members');
    foreach($users as &$member) if ($member != $uid){
        $members->addChild('user', $member);
    }
}
$xml = $accounts->asXml();
```